# How to retrieve a list of address of youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, webaddress

I am about to analyze youtube channel related to specific keyword like game, computer science and etc.

I want to get their web address of youtube.

I tried to get address one by one manually by clicking right button of my mouse.

As it was too laborious, I need a solution.
Is there any program or method to do this?

Comment: GreaseMonkey and custom script

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then, I need to make custom script which can automatically copy and paste the address since there is no specific program for this. Am I right?

Comment: Don't know about any and SO is not a place to ask this. I'm suggesting GreaseMonkey, because you can use small piece of javascript and create list of videos that can be downloaded as txt for example. I did something similar for one private video system in a few hours